# Owncloud Auditing logs

Tags: owncloud

How can I see the logs of documents/files which are uploaded or downloaded in OwnCloud by users?

I want to see all the logs of file sharing, who has uploaded a file and who has downloaded a file. Even if the user has shared a file by link. Currently I am able to only see general logs in OwnCloud.log file.